# Jpgraph: How to manually set Ranges for X-axis and Y-asxis

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jpgraph

Hello People i need to make some change to Jp graph...

1)i need to set X-axis range from '0' to '100' with step size '10'.

2)i need to set Y-axis range from '-5' to '6' with step size '1'.

3)i need to label the point selected on the graph, something like if the selected values are

'70' and '2'(which is shown in the graph),i wanna name it as 'point1' , if the second selected point lies on '80' and '3' then i want to name it as 'point2'..'point1 and point2 should come on the graph itself...'..is there a way to fix this?please help me to do fix these issues...

Comment: Fix what? You haven't shown any code.

Comment: He's just asking for a possibility to set the scale of the x-axis and y-axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$graph = new Graph(450,400,'auto');
$graph->SetScale("textlin");

// set major and minor tick positions manually
$graph->yaxis->SetTickPositions(array(0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100), array(5,15,25,35,45,55,65,75,85,95);

$graph->xaxis->SetTickLabels(array(-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6));

$graph->yaxis->HideLine(false);
$graph->yaxis->HideTicks(false,false);
$graph->xaxis->HideLine(false);
$graph->xaxis->HideTicks(false,false);
```

Thats point 1 and 2. I dont know about 3 but they're plenty on online tutorials. Check out http://jpgraph.net/